# Categorizing MailMerge on ONE Page - Directory/Catalogue

Tags: directory, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to get the mail merge work with directory as the source that would help me categorize the records in my current template.

I am using this field code: `{QUOTE{IF{MERGESEQ}=1{SET Key ""}}"{IF{MERGEFIELD Description}<> {KEY}"{IF{MERGESEQ}>1"
"}
Values for {MERGEFIELD Description}{SET Key{MERGEFIELD Description}}
Input
"}{MERGEFIELD ColDesc}
"}`

Now the output I get is fine for a new fresh document, but when I try this code with an existing template, what it outputs is a document for each record it merges.

What I would like to have is a kind of this output on one page:

```
Details for the record selected from the file provided:


Values for 'Subjects'
Input
Study ID
Class ID
Subject Name
Student ID

Values for 'Visits'
Input
Visit ID
Visit date
Room No.
Summary 
etc.....
```

But what my output is the following:

```
Details for the record selected from the file provided:
Values for 'Subjects'
Input
Study ID
Class ID
Subject Name
Student ID


Details for the record selected from the file provided:
Values for 'Visits'
Input
Visit ID
Visit date
Room No.
Summary
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

Best

Comment: I agree by default, Mail Merge using directory tells word to repeat all the contents in the sheet. ref: http://lis.dickinson.edu/technology/training/Tutorials/ms2007/word/word_directory_merge.pdf  

But I wanted to have the output my way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I was able to figure out my problem.

I followed this link http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/111149-Mailmerge-Tutorial-Create-Sorted-Listings-(2000-2010)

and in that

The tutorial shows how to do the categorisation. From what I've described, it seems the field under the topic 'Merge Records By Category' would serve as the basis for the project. If you want to output some content only when the first record is merged, simply modify this part of the field:

```
{IF{MERGESEQ}= 1 {SET Key " "}}
to, for example:
{IF{MERGESEQ}= 1 "{SET Key " "}Record 1"}
```

Cool, SO far so good.